# Update value from json dictionary by key in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, jsonpath

I need to update a dictionary value in a field in a table that contains json in Microsoft SQL.

So if the table and data is this:

```
CREATE TABLE Visits
(   
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [AdditionalInfo] NVARCHAR(4000) NULL
)

insert into visits
   (id,AdditionalInfo)
values
   (newid(),'{"LastVisit":{"4d635993-3829-ec11-b6e6-000d3a0cc942":"2022-10-11T12:00:00Z"}}')
insert into visits
   (id,AdditionalInfo)
values
   (newid(),'{"LastVisit":{"4d635993-3829-ec11-b6e6-000d3a0cc942":"2022-10-11T12:00:00Z","7f90a25b-f5d4-eb11-bacb-0022481aa333":"2022-10-11T14:42:00Z"}}')
```

I want to update the time of the last visit, given an arbitary key.

For example, where the key is '7f90a25b-f5d4-eb11-bacb-0022481aa333', I want it now to be '2023-07-06T13:00:00Z'

So the second row with the AdditionalInfo field that was:

```
{"LastVisit":{"4d635993-3829-ec11-b6e6-000d3a0cc942":"2022-10-11T12:00:00Z","7f90a25b-f5d4-eb11-bacb-0022481aa333":"2022-10-11T14:42:00Z"}}
```

should now be:

```
{"LastVisit":{"4d635993-3829-ec11-b6e6-000d3a0cc942":"2022-10-11T12:00:00Z","7f90a25b-f5d4-eb11-bacb-0022481aa333":"2023-07-06T13:00:00Z"}}
```

and the first row is left as it was.

Any help would be apprieciated.

I did get as far as to be able to select the row:

```
select id, additionalinfo from visits
where exists(select [key] , [value] from openjson(additionalinfo, '$.LastVisit') where [key] = '7f90a25b-f5d4-eb11-bacb-0022481aa333')
```

But I got stuck getting any further with updating the value. I did look into json_modify, but that needs a jsonpath, and I can't find the syntax for a dictionary (key/value, where the keys are all different).

Comment: Use `JSON_MODIFY()` to update the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual approach depends on the structure of your JSON content, but in case of JSON object(s) without nested JSON arrays, a statement using `JSON_MODIFY()` is an option:

```
UPDATE Visits
SET [AdditionalInfo] = JSON_MODIFY(
   [AdditionalInfo],
   '$.LastVisit."7f90a25b-f5d4-eb11-bacb-0022481aa333"',
   '2023-07-06T13:00:00Z'
)
WHERE JSON_VALUE(
  [AdditionalInfo],
  '$.LastVisit."7f90a25b-f5d4-eb11-bacb-0022481aa333"'
) IS NOT NULL
```

Starting from SQL Server 2022, you may use `JSON_PATH_EXISTS()` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
...
WHERE JSON_PATH_EXISTS(
  [AdditionalInfo],
  '$.LastVisit."7f90a25b-f5d4-eb11-bacb-0022481aa333"'
) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this i guess:

```sql
with data as (
select '{"LastVisit":{"4d635993-3829-ec11-b6e6-000d3a0cc942":"2022-10-11T12:00:00Z"}}' as json
union select '{"LastVisit":{"4d635993-3829-ec11-b6e6-000d3a0cc942":"2022-10-11T12:00:00Z","7f90a25b-f5d4-eb11-bacb-0022481aa333":"2022-10-11T14:42:00Z"}}'
)
select *
, json_modify(json, '$.LastVisit."7f90a25b-f5d4-eb11-bacb-0022481aa333"', '2023-01-01T12:12:00')
from data
where json_value(json, '$.LastVisit."7f90a25b-f5d4-eb11-bacb-0022481aa333"') is not null
```

WHERE makes sure you get correct json, and the json_modify modifies the node you're looking for